# Resolving error C3821: managed type or function cannot be used in an unmanaged function

Tags: .net, windows, c++-cli, interop

I'm writing a C++/CLI layer to handle some interop.

The native API populates a complex structure involving fixed arrays, unions, anonymous structures, etc:

```
typedef struct DECLSPEC_ALIGN(16) _FOO {
    union {
        BAR Bar;
        struct {
           POP   Array[8];
           DWORD More;
        };
    };
} FOO, *PFOO;
```

I'm trying to translate this data structure to more "sane" .NET class, for consumption by C#.  The problem is, I can't use this legacy structure, and `gcnew` my new class in the same function:

```
Foo^ Test::GetFoo(HANDLE h)
{
    FOO foo;                              // Necessarily unmanaged

    if (!::GetFoo(h, &foo))
        throw gcnew Exception("GetFoo failed");

    Foo^ result = gcnew Foo();            // Necessarily managed

    // populate result

    return result;
}
```

Doing so gives the error:

> Error    2   error C3821: 'void Test::GetFoo(HANDLE)': managed type or function cannot be used in an unmanaged function

If a native structure and a `gcnew` cannot exist in the same function, how can one ever hope to (even manually) marshall data between the two?

Many Q/A here involve *wrapping* unmanaged classes, which seems to be irrelevant here.

Comment: @HansPassant Not so. `/clr` is on, and I have no `#pragma managed` or `unmanaged` statements anywhere. Attempting to force managed code generation with `/clr:pure` gives the error `Test::GetFoo cannot be generated in managed code: 'Aligned data types not supported in managed code'; compile with /clr to generate a mixed image`. I'm guessing the `DECLSPEC_ALIGN` is what's killing me? Although I'd be surprised if a union was allowed anywhere near managed code.

Comment: Okay, I got it.  Please *do* avoid posting impossible error messages, GetFoo() doesn't return void.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry about that, I'm obviously working from a larger code base, and tried to distill the problem down to a minimal example without *actually* creating that minimal example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Aligned data types not supported in managed code

That's the real error message, unfortunately it does not show up in the Error List window.  You can only see it in the Output window.  Something to keep in mind when compiler error messages look bizarre.

And yes, it is accurate, managed code doesn't run with the stack alignment guarantees that are needed to get this structure aligned.  32-bit code runs with an alignment of 4, 64-bit code can provide 8.  Not good enough to get 16.  Nothing the compiler can do about it either, the usual stack pointer manipulations are not available in IL, that screws up the metadata that the jitter generates that tells the garbage collector where the look for object references when it walks the stack.

So, no can do, you cannot make it a local variable.  You've got choices, the most straight-forward way is to allocate it:

```
#include <malloc.h>
....

    FOO* value = (FOO*)_aligned_malloc(sizeof(FOO), __alignof(FOO));
    try {
        // etc...
    }
    finally {
        _aligned_free(value);
    }
```

Comment: I can always count on you, Hans to answer my .NET interop questions. Always appreciate your thorough answers.